# I cant download a specific app on an emulator

Tags: android-emulator, bluestacks

So I am trying to download stockspile (trading app). First I thought that my problem was that internet so I used US proxy. But I keep getting the issue your device isnt compatible with this version.

Does anyone know how to bypass this ?

Answer (score 3):

Because of emulation speed Android emulators usually emulate a x86/x86_64 Android device. real Android devices are ARM/Arm64. If the app uses native libraries and don't provide them for x86 or x86_64 you can not run or install the app on such an emulator. The emulator included in Android SDK/Android Studio includes some images (e.g. "Android 12.0 API Level 31 Google Play | x86_64") that have an internal ARM emulation so it should be possible to install an arm or arm64 only app.

You can check the supported CPU types of an emulator by executing `adb shell getprop ro.product.cpu.abilist`

Possible values in output:

- `x86` -> 32bit x86 apps are supported
- `x86_64` -> 64bit x86 apps are supported
- `armeabi` -> 32 bit arm apps are supported
- `armeabi-v7a` -> 32 bit arm apps are supported (today just an alias for `armeabi`)
- `arm64-v8a`-> 64bit arm apps are supported

If it outputs for example `x86,armeabi-v7a,armeabi` then this means it can execute 32bit x86 and 32bit arm code. If your app is only available as 64bit arm version then it won't work.

The best way to check for which platforms an app is available is to look at the available downloads at https://apkmirror.com, https://apkpure.com or any other web site Apps providing apps for manual installation.